# Problems with KML layers

Tags: api, maps

My map has 9 layers which can be toggled on and off by means of a tick box. Each layer is loaded in by JS. My problem is that only 5 of the nine load when their tick box is active. Is there a limit on how many kml layers can be loaded in to v3 api? In total there is less than 1mb, though they do have quite a few custom marker icons.

Thanks
Darren

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It is a recently introduced bug, and I've filed a ticket to have it looked into.

Comment: This was a bug in the way KML was rendered, and a fix for this rolled out last week.  It seems to work correctly now but please update if there's still an issue.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I've had to come up with another solution, but it's good to know that it's fixed for the future.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a eerily familiar-sounding issue. I am working with KML files in similar fashion (an array of map layers as KML files are picked/loaded by JS via a tick box, not big, although quite a few custom marker icons, long descriptions, etc..).

I have just now become aware of what seems like a NEW limit. Wish I could be more help, but I will share what I know.

In my case, the exact same code was working fine as far back as June 2011 and the map has been viewed/used by 1000s of people. It's a custom v3 api map for an annual event. The 'legend' has about 34 layers containing lines or markers, classified by type, any of which could be 'on' at any given time. The default, and most commonly used, setup had about 12 "layers" on. Only one of the layers (happens to be the last one in the array when it loads) is one that changes significantly from year to year. It's also the most important one. If people were getting significant errors in June 2011 in some browser/OS, I would have heard about it. It was this file that I sat down to "quickly" edit and re-upload in time for the 2012 event. I hadn't even touched it before I noticed that something was wrong. I haven't needed to look at the map since last year, so unfortunately I can't be more precise as to when this started happening.

Findings/Conclusions/Ideas?:

- dumping the browser cache does nothing
- Through trial and error, I found that it will actually load up to 6 "layers", but it seems to depend on the size/type/juju? of any given kML file in the comma delineated list. But, like you, it's usually around 5 or 6.
- Oddly, the KML files themselves seem to be there in the background. Invisible markers will affect the mouse pointer "on hover over" and their info boxes will show up when clicked. Strange.
- This problem is definitely less than a year old for me.
- If not somehow related to some new action of Google's (in which case I would suspect we'd hear about it or have found something in the API forums..) perhaps it is related to some new limits placed by one of our servers and is simply a coincidence?

---> hmm. I recently had a wordpress site's menu item limit issue and got my hosting provider to change some suhosin request limits(?) I can try migrating the source file to another server, and see if it works from there. If it does, that would be a significant clue, and I will report back.

Other than that, I have no idea. Just thought I'd share what I've learned and hope someone else has some idea of what's going on.

Comment: Hi Anders, I agree this is definitely a new problem - my site was working fine. I'm getting exactly the same issue as you. I don't think it's a server issue as I have tried loading the KMLs from different servers. My solution is to have only one KML active at a time via checkboxes. I'll let you know how I get on.