# What does "Maximum number of total document-wide features"< 1,000 actually mean? KML file limit

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The limitations for google maps are documented here https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport but I was just wondering what "Maximum number of total document-wide features" actually means does this mean the total number of points in a line or lines?

I have a map where I am loading around 15 kml files with about 80-150 co-ordinates each and I've noticed recently that the files aren't being displayed properly - some are appearing as "ghosts" - I can select them but I can't see them.

Have I gone over the limit?

Regards,
Lea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something appears to have changed recently about the way KML layers are loaded in Google Maps; developers have been experiencing similar problems as indicated by some recent questions here on stackoverflow:

- [Issues with KML Layers limit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10804070/1314132)
- [Problems with KML layers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10807261/1314132)
- [Google Map API v3 displays only 5 layers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10821682/1314132)
- [Google Maps Number of KML layers limit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10835276/1314132)

And elsewhere on the web:

- http://blog.appsgoogleplus.com/google/17566/google-map-api-v3-displays-only-5-layers/

[Bug Report #4185](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4185) was recently filed on the Google Maps Issues page; it may relate to you problem. Not sure if you are also experiencing something that seems to be related to a specific number of KML Layers, but hope this info helps -

Comment: I think you are right Sean - spent all Saturday worrying about this one and discovered the bug here on Sunday. It Looks like it's fixed now!!

Comment: The limit is around 24 to 25 kmls now - waiting on this issue http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2384 now!